# How to start the Remote Access service if get error 711?

Tags: windows-7, usb-modem

When I connect the USB modem I am unable to connect to internet because of this error on Windows 7 Ultimate.

Comment: Which version of windows are you running?

Comment: Windows 7 Ultimate......

Answer (score 0):

The below is taken from a [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/330163) that applies to Windows XP, but you can replicate the steps in Windows 7 and see if it makes any difference:

> 1. Click Start, right-click My Computer, and then click Manage.
> 2. Double-click Services and Applications, and then double-click
>      Services.
> 3. Right-click Telephony, and then click Properties.
> 4. On the General tab, click Manual next to Startup type.
> 5. On the General tab, click Start under Service status, and then click
>      OK.
> 6. Repeat steps 3 - 5 for the Remote Access Connection Manager service
>      and for the Remote Access Auto Connection Manager service.

Comment: svchost is running on my system.It may be hacked.What to do.

Comment: Run a virus/malware scan in safe mode.